# I want to block an url with htaccess and <FilesMatch> with quest mark (not query string)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, query-string, blocking

I found a lot of topics about blocking query string url via .htaccess on stackoverflow. But I need to block a bunch of not existing urls :like http://www.vvdealblas.nl/?/member/login (urls from the old cms).

I want to do this with FilesMatch, something like:

```
<FilesMatch "^{regex}$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do that via `FilesMatch`

Comment: What do you mean by "block". Return 404  or 403?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that via `FilesMatch` since you want to match `QUERY_STRING`. Use `mod_rewrite` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/member/login$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ - [F]
```